# What is EOF and how to trigger it?

Tags: command-line, c

This is my C source code.

When I build it in Ubuntu, it starts to get characters but I don't know how to end the program, as it does not end by inputting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or a carriage return.

What does EOF mean? How can I trigger it?

This source is also on a book by Dennis Ritchie:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    /* count digits, white space, others */
main ()
{
  int c, i, nwhite, nother;
  int ndigit[10];
  nwhite = nother = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ndigit[i] = 0;
  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
      ++ndigit[c - '0'];
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
      ++nwhite;
    else
      ++nother;
  printf ("digits =");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf (" %d", ndigit[i]);
  printf (", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Comment: in C language `-1` is equivalent of EOF. It is defined in `/usr/include/stdio.h` as a macro constant

Comment: Relevant reading: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12389518/3701431

Comment: @edwardtorvalds entering `-1` as input doesn't work   :)

Comment: I think the same Dennis Ritchie book explains this.

Comment: Also relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell (None of the answers posted to this question is entirely correct.)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds yes, and ctrl+d triggers EOT character, not -1 . read my answer. I explained it all there

Comment: @edwardtorvalds  I've read the library file. Read this as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character  . Also , do `echo $'\04' |  cat -A  ` this in terminal. It will say `^D` . ASCII code for EOT character is Ctrl + D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Tl;dr

You can generally "trigger EOF" in a program running in a terminal with a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keystroke right after the last input flush.

---

> What does EOF mean? How can I trigger it?

EOF means End-Of-File.

"Triggering EOF" in this case roughly means "making the program aware that no more input will be sent".

In this case, since `getchar()` will return a negative number if no character is read, the execution is terminated.

But this doesn't only apply to your specific program, it applies to many different tools.

In general "triggering EOF" can be done with a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keystroke right after the last input flush (i.e. by sending an empty input).

For example with `cat`:

```
% cat >file # Hit ENTER
foo # Hit ENTER and CTRL+D
%
```

What's happening under the hood when hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is that the input typed since the last input flush is flushed; when this happens to be an empty input the `read()` syscall called on the program's STDIN returns `0`, `getchar()` returns  a negative number (`-1` in the GNU C library) and this is in turn interpreted as EOF<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sub>1 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1516177/4316166</sub>

Comment: Compilation works, because comma delimitation is not bound by being in the same line. Other than that, great explanation on EOF :)

Comment: @PauliusŠukys Huh, you're right. My C is a bit rusty. :)

Comment: iirc EOF is *not* defined to be -1 per the standard. It's just what it happens to be in glibc for example.

Comment: @larkey That's correct: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/EOF-and-Errors.html

Comment: EOF does not 'consist in sending an "empty input"', and the SO answer you cite does not say otherwise. It is an out of band signal. In the case of a terminal it is sent by typing Ctrl/d.

Comment: @EJP The Stack Overflow answer I'm citing makes the point that a `read()` syscall returning the lenght of an empty input (0) is interpreted as the EOF, so that answer is wrong? Mind to elaborate on the "out of band signal"? As far as I'm concerned CTRL+D is not a "signal" intended in the traditional *nix sense.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: EOF is not a character, it's a macro used for evaluating negative return of an input-reading function. One can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send `EOT` character which will force function return `-1`

**Every programmer must RTFM**

Let us refer to  "C A Reference Manual", by Harbison and Steele, 4th ed. from 1995, page 317:

> The negative integer EOF is a value that is not an encoding of a "real
>   character" . . . For example fget (section 15.6) **returns  EOF** when
>   at end-of-file, because there is no "real character" to be read.

Essentially `EOF` isn't a character, but rather an **integer value** implemented in `stdio.h` to represent `-1`. Thus, kos's answer is correct as far as that goes, but it's not about receiving "empty" input. Important note is that  here EOF serves as *return value* (of `getchar()`) comparison , not to signify an actual character. The `man getchar` supports that:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> fgetc(), getc() and getchar() return the character read as an  unsigned
>     char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.
>
> gets()  and  fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end
>     of file occurs while no characters have been read.
>
> ungetc() returns c on success, or EOF on error.

Consider the `while` loop - its primary purpose is to repeat action *if condition in the brackets is true*. Look again:

```
while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
```

It basically says   keep doing stuff if  `c =  getchar()` returns successful code (`0` or above ; it's a common thing by the way, try running successful command, then `echo $?` and then failed `echo $?` and see numbers they return ).   So if we successfully get character and assing to C , returned status code is 0, failed is -1. `EOF` is defined as `-1`.  Therefore  when condition `-1 == -1` occurs, loops stops. And when will that happen ? When there is no more character to get, when `c = getchar()` fails. You could write `while ((c = getchar ()) != -1)` and it still would work

Also, let's go back to the actual code, here's an excerpt from `stdio.h`

```
/* End of file character.
   Some things throughout the library rely on this being -1.  */
#ifndef EOF
# define EOF (-1)
#endif
```

**ASCII codes and EOT**

Although EOF character is not an actual character, however, there exists an `EOT` (End of Transmission) character, which has ASCII decimal value of 04; it is linked to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut ( represented also as meta character `^D`). The end of transmission chracter used to signify closing of a stream of data way back when computers were used to control telephone connections , hence "end of transmission" naming.

So it is possible to send that ascii value to the program like so, note the `$'\04'` which is the EOT:

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./a.out  <<< "a,b,c $'\04'"                                  
digits = 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0, white space = 2, other = 9
```

Thus , we can say that it does exists, but it is not printable

**Side Note**

We often forget that in the past computers weren't as versatile - designers has to make use of every keyboard key available. Thus , sending `EOT` character with CtrlD is still "sending a character" , not unlike typing capital A, ShiftA, you still make give computer an input with available keys. Thus EOT is a real character in a sense that it does come from user, it is readable by computer (though not printable, non visible by humans), it exists in computer memory

**Byte Commander's comment**

> If you try to read from /dev/null, that should return an EOF as well,
>   right? Or what do I get there?

Yes, exactly right, because in `/dev/null` there is no actual character to be read , hence it `c = getchar()` will return `-1` code, and program will quit right away. Again **command doesn't return EOF. EOF is just constant variable equal to -1 , which we use to compare return code of getchar function**. `EOF` doesn't exist as character, it's just a static value inside `stdio.h`.

Demo:

```
# cat /dev/null shows there's no readable chars
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat /dev/null | cat -A        

# Bellow is simple program that will open /dev/null for reading. Note the use of literal -1                                   
   DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat readNull.c                                               
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
   char c;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/dev/null", "r");

    if (file) 
    {
    printf ("Before while loop\n");
        while ((c = getc(file)) != -1)
            putchar(c);
    printf("After while loop\n"); 
    fclose(file);
    }
}

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ gcc readNull.c -o readNull                                   

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./readNull
Before while loop
After while loop
```

**Another nail in the coffin**

Sometimes it is attempted to be proved that EOF is a character with a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%c", EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

Problem with that is that char datatype can be a signed or unsigned value. In addition they are smallest addressable datatype which makes them very very useful in microcontrollers, where memory is limited. So instead of declaring `int foo = 25;` it is common to see in microcontrollers with small memory `char foo = 25;` or something similar.  In addition , [chars may be signed or unsigned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

One could verify that the size in bytes with a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Size of int: %lu\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("Sieze of char: %lu\n",sizeof(char));
    //printf("%s", EOF);
    return 0;
}

skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./EOF                                                        
Size of int: 4
Sieze of char: 1
```

What exactly is the point ? The point is that EOF is defined as -1, but *char datatype can print integer values*.

OK . . .so what if we try to print char as string ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s", EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously an error, but nonetheless,error will tell us something interesting:

> skolodya@ubuntu:$ gcc EOF.c  -o EOF
>   EOF.c: In function ‘main’: EOF.c:4:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects
>   argument of type ‘char *’, **but argument 2 has type ‘int’**
>   [-Wformat=]
>        printf("%s", EOF);

**Hex values**

Printing EOF as a hex value gives `FFFFFFFF`, a 16 bit (8 byte) value, two's compliment of a `-1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("This is EOF: %X\n", EOF);
    printf("This is Z: %X\n",'Z');
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./EOF                                                        
This is EOF: FFFFFFFF
This is Z: 5A
```

Another curious thing occurs with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   char c;
   if (c = getchar())
    printf ("%x",c);
    return 0;
}
```

If one presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> , we get hex value 41 , obviously same as in ASCII table. But for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> , we have `ffffffff` , again - the return value of `getchar()` stored in `c`.

```
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ gcc  EOF.c -o ASDF.asdf                                      

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./ASDF.asdf                                                  
A
41
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./ASDF.asdf                                                  
ffffffff
```

**Refer to other languages**

Notice that other language avoid this confusion, because they operate on evaluating a function exit status, not comparing it with a macro.
How does one read file in Java ?

```
    File inputFile  = new File (filename);
    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while (readFile.hasNext())
        { //more code bellow  }
```

How about python?

```
with open("/etc/passwd") as file:
     for line in file:
          print line
```

Comment: Great point, indeed a character is sent somehow at some point.

Comment: I think the EOF character is something that has been lost in translation, since it's not an actual character , but EOT is an actual, ascii character .  Go figure !

Comment: If you try to read from `/dev/null`, that should return an EOF as well, right? Or what do I get there?

Comment: @ByteCommander lets find out. Do cat /dev/null  |  cat -A.

Comment: @ByteCommander added section addressing your comment

Answer (score 2):

**EOF** stands for *end of file*. While I do not know how to trigger the following symbol, you can run the following program through piping a file, which sends the **EOF** signal at the end:

```
echo "Some sample text" | ./a.out
```

where `a.out` is your compiled source

Comment: Upvoted this already, however on a side note EOF is not a character, I think the misconception arises from the fact that is signaled through a CTRL keystroke, which is usually the way to input non-printable characters. As I understand all that actually happens is that all input is flushed and being the input to be flushed empty `read()` (syscall) will return `0`, which is interpreted as EOF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516177/4316166

Comment: @kos, You're right, it's a signal afterall.