# How to make terminal start quite fresh?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

In one of my previous sessions using terminal, I typed `^D` by mistake.
And now every time I start the terminal, there's this:

```
^D: command not found
```

What should I do?

I have used the command `clear` several times, but every time I start the terminal, that line appears again.

[image]

Comment: Check your `~/.bashrc` - it probably has the `^D`. Delete it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of [installing Cisco AnyConnect client](http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~jstern/uci_vpn_ubuntu/), I had typed

```
$ cat >> ~/.bash_aliases
alias vpn='/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn'
alias vpnui='/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnui'
^D
```

So the non existing command `^D` was written in my `~/.bash_aliases` file which is run every time I open the terminal.

To solve the problem, type:

```
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

and delete the command `^D`

Comment: If you weren't aware, the `^D` is [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for End Of Transmission (U+4), which indicates an [end-of-file (EOF)](https://askubuntu.com/q/724990/301745).

Comment: FYI, the author probably intended you to type `CTRL+D` rather than literal `^D`