# How to write to crontab using here document syntax << >>?

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, redirect

I'm trying to add a cron job without actually opening vim or nano. Something like this:

```
$ crontab -e << echo '* 0/10 * * *  some command'
```

I'm seeing [stuff online like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724990/what-is-eof-and-how-to-trigger-it) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash), but honestly it's kinda confusing.

Comment: Use `crontab -`  to make take input from stdin.

Answer (score 4):

First create make a copy of your user's `crontab` file using:

```
crontab -l > ${USER}_crontab
```

then  you can easily work with `username_crontab` as it's a normal file, edit it or redirect anything to it in different ways.

For example append a new job:

```
echo '* 0/10 * * *  some command' >> ${USER}_crontab
```

then install the file using:

```
crontab ${USER}_crontab
```

---

You can also do it all in once like this:

```
cat <<< "* * * * *  cmd1" > my_jobs; crontab my_jobs
```

or:

```
cat > my_jobs <<E                   
* * * * *  cmd1
* * * * *  cmd2
E

crontab my_jobs
```

Comment: Thanks for these solutions! This is interesting. Both methods require we write (>) to a file first before adding a cron. Is it not possible then without first writing to a separate file?

Comment: You can write to any file and then install it using `crontab file_name` like the last two solution.

Comment: Sorry if my english is bad. I'm asking if its possible to do without writing to file.

Comment: There is no way that I'm aware of... when you are using `crontab -e` you are actually asking for an editor to edit your crontab file.